# Android Emulator actual screen size

Tags: android, android-emulator, screen-size

I want to optimize my app. I have a user with a Samsung Galaxy Note, 1280x800, 320dpi, Large Screen.

How do I set up the emulator's actual inch-screen size?
If I choose WXGA800 with 320dpi it makes a normal sized Version. How do I make it large?

Edit. Thanks for your answers, but that isn't the point. I know how to set up a an Emulator screen resolution and dpi. Actually I want an emulator to edit "layout-large-xhdpi" layouts but I get a "layout-normal-xhdpi" using 1280x800 with 320dpi in the AVD Manager. I simply want to change xlarge to large. Is there a way?

Edit2 Okay,found a workaround by temporarily removing the layout for normal sized xdhpi devices(Galaxy Nexus) and editing the Galaxy Note Layout as if it were some kind of "xhdpi" layout. But still it is strange to me, that it is impossible to edit directly a specific folder file like "layout-large-xhdpi". Found only in the Layout-Editor the possibility to add a screen size but unfortunately it won't make my layout.

Nevertheless I will have to make my layouts more flexible to have less problems ;-)

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do that by opening your **AVD Manager** from **Eclipse** and when you are creating the emulator just check the Resolution radio button and input your desired screen size. Don't forget to change the density of the screen too. If you just want to emulate a Tablet you can simply make an emulator with *Android API 2.3* or higher and it should have the desired dimensions..

Answer (score 0):

@le chiffre : may I know why you want to increase the screen, as from my experience, if you use Eclipse then I think you can't increase the screen resolution of Emulator (if I'm wrong correct me please). The size of the emulator in landscape mode: width:800 and height:400 and I get this by this code

```
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth(); 
int height = display.getHeight();
```

and if you want to scale your application, pictures,etc., you need to get the device width and height, so you don't need to worry about screen resolution. But I don't think emulator size can be increased.

Thx and hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse when you start the avd, you can set the option scale display to real size and set the display size and dpi.

Window -> Android sdk and avd Manager -> start -> you will get option here